# Laravel App on Google App Engine Hangs with Responses Larger Than 450KB

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, httpresponse

I am facing a perplexing issue with my Laravel application hosted on Google App Engine (GAE)Standard ENV. While the application runs flawlessly in a local environment, I encounter a specific problem when hosted on GAE: API responses larger than approximately 450KB never complete; the requests hang and I receive no error and no logs are fired.

#### Context

- **Local Environment**: The application operates without issues. I can receive JSON responses of any size, including payloads of several MBs.
- **Google App Engine Environment**: Requests with responses larger than 450KB hang. There are no error logs in GAE indicating the problem.
- **Type of Responses**: The issue occurs with both JSON responses and rendering of HTML Blade pages.
- **GAE Instance Size**: I have tried scaling the instance resources up to the maximum, but the issue persists.
- **Tests Conducted**: I have performed tests with responses of various sizes to isolate the issue, but it seems to be specifically linked to responses over 450KB.

#### What I've Already Checked

1. **App Engine Configuration**: I haven't found any specific settings that could limit the size of the responses.
2. **Payload Limits**: I am aware that the payload limits on GAE are well above 450KB.
3. **Timeouts and Resources**: The response processing time never exceeds one second, so it seems not to be a timeout or insufficient resources issue.
4. **Logging**: There are no errors or warnings in the GAE logs that indicate the cause of the problem.

#### Specific Questions

1. **Are there hidden settings or limitations in GAE that could be causing this behavior?**
2. **Could it be an issue related to handling large responses specific to the GAE Standard environment?**
3. **What other troubleshooting steps could I take to further isolate the cause?**

Any suggestions or experiences with similar issues would be extremely helpful.

Comment: When testing on local, do you run your app with ```dev_appserver.py```? If you didn't try and see if you encounter any issues

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using App Engine in PHP 8.2? If yes, this is the problem. Google has this issue registered: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297140655?pli=1

Current workaround is to use PHP 8.1. I've had the same problem, made the change and it's working again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting crazy with this, because I couldn't debug it. I was actually using PHP8.2 . Downgrading to PHP8.1 it works perfectly.

Comment: this issue cost me 8 full, uninterrupted, development hours. Thank you so much for finding the solution to this. what a huge waste of time