# Slow loading of large php files on PHP 8.2 gloogle cloud engine

Tags: php, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, php-8.2

We're using cache files that consist of a combination of simple PHP code and HTML. These cache files are stored with a PHP filename.

Some files exceed 400 KB, and I've noticed that Google App Engine, specifically with PHP 8.2 runtime, exhibits significantly slow loading times—more than 60,000 ms. When using PHP 7.4, the response time is only 300 ms.

Are there any limitations in this new PHP version or within the Google App Engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it's the same problem of this question: [Laravel App on Google App Engine Hangs with Responses Larger Than 450KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546339/laravel-app-on-google-app-engine-hangs-with-responses-larger-than-450kb)

If not hangs, become very slow.

Google has an issue open: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297140655?pli=1

Current workaround is to use PHP 8.1.

Comment: I spent 5 days trying to find a way to fix or understand what is happening. Thank you, Mr Pereira. I started using PHP 8.1.